# elementwise inclusion in Naive Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the $\epsilon$-inclusion relation in Naive Set Theory reflexive?

I.e do we have: $X\in X$ in Naive Set Theory?

Comment: No; naive set theory includes the empty set, and $\varnothing\notin\varnothing$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I always need to think about the emptyset for anomalies. Thanks!

Comment: @Arturo Magidin.  Did you state $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$ as a counterexample, or as an instance of a general rule : $\forall S ( S\notin S)$ ? I thought that , at least in ZFC,  this irreflexive property  held for every set whatever, am I wrong?

Comment: @VinceVickler The question is whether it is reflexive, not whether it is irreflexive, and about Naive set theory, not ZFC.